# Name of Electra's brother

Tags: greek, sophocles, tragedy, atreidai

In Sophocles' *Electra*, it is revealed at the end that one of the guards there is Electra's long lost brother. What is the name of this guard? I have looked for it online, and in the book he is referred to by his title.

Comment: Eh? Orestes, of course. The tragedy tells the story of his revenge, I'd thought he wouldn't be easy to forget.

Comment: Its not Orestes. The person who I am talking about was never referred to by name in the book.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​What book? There's no mention of another brother in the play (check out [this translation](http://classics.mit.edu/Sophocles/electra.html) for example). Could it be that the book you've read wasn't particularly faithful to the original material?

Comment: The book I am refering to is part of the dover thrift collection, here is a link to it on google books:   https://books.google.com/books?id=844G8qkdfX4C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the passage in question is unreadable through Google Books, I fear you've just misunderstood the translation. This is the part, right?

http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0188%3Acard%3D1339

That's not her brother. She has but one brother, Orestes, and the "guardian" is actually the pedagogue (paidagōgos).

Comment: yes, you are right! I was thinking of the Guardian. Thank you.